# vue element checkbox not working in edit mode

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am using checkbox given by vue-element, visit https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/checkbox.
But in edit mode they are not able to select anymore.
Please help me out.

```
<el-checkbox-group v-model="form.activity_type" size="small">
      <el-checkbox-button
        v-for="(all_type,index) in all_activity"
        :key="index"
        :label="all_type.id"
      >{{all_type.activity_type_name}}</el-checkbox-button>
    </el-checkbox-group>
```

Comment: You should try to avoid using edit mode.

Comment: @IVOGELOV But i need to edit as its a requirement

Comment: Hm, then you can either fire an issue on Github or try to manually debug the code for the component to see where it flaws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<el-checkbox-group v-model="form.activity_type" size="small">
    <e`enter code here`l-checkbox-button
        v-for="(all_type,index) in all_activity"
        :key="index"
        :label="all_type.id">
        {{all_type.activity_type_name}}
    </el-checkbox-button>
</el-checkbox-group>

Hi you in order to show checkbox in edit mode you can do it like this:
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                activity_type: []
            }
        };
    }

import {activityData} from "@/api/activity";

2)under method function:
    activityData(id).then(response => {
        this.form = response.res;
    });
3) and then from your controller function you can pass data in this format:
    $allData = [];
    $allData['activity_type'] = array(1,3);//the ids one you want to show check
    return response()->json(["res" => $allData]);
```